# How to read the value from excel and use that value as Input on application on Tricentis Tosca?

Tags: excel, tosca

On Tricentis Tosca, I have used Tbox->Excel Modules
Given the Tbox define excel range->Given the start cell and end cell.
But i don't know how to read that value from excel and use on Application using Tosca.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to save the Excel value to a buffer using the [TBox Excel Range Manipulation](https://documentation.tricentis.com/tosca/1520/en/content/standard_subset/engines_3.0/excel.htm#range_manip) module and then [use that buffer value](https://documentation.tricentis.com/tosca/1520/en/content/articles/buffer_this.htm) in later test steps.